# A question about metric space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $$X = \left\{ (x_n)_{n=1}^{\infty} \mid x_n \in \mathbb{R}, \quad 0 \leq x_n \leq 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}.$$

The set $X$ equipped with metric $d(x,y) = \sup \{ \mid x_n - y_n \mid : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

> I know that:
>
> The metric space $Y$ is compact if and only if the every sequence in $Y$ has a convergent sub-sequence.

But I could not prove, why $X$ is not compact by defined  metric?

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

You can prove the space is not compact by finding a sequence without a convergent subsequence.

**Hint**:

Like a lot of times, you should try your search for a counterexample by looking at simple things.

Think about very simple vectors in $X$. Very simple ones. With a whole lot of zeroes. Like, as many zeroes as you can get (i.e., with as few nonzero elements as possible). Also, to make them even simpler, have the nonzero element be something simple. Like a constant value. Some simple constant value, so it'll be easy to calculate with it.

Answer (score 0):

That is not compact .
Counterexample: $x_n:-n^{th}$ coordinate is 1 else $0$.